# Neo4j - find nodes of type A which have more than X children of type B

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to find all nodes of A type which have more than X children of B type.

By child I mean that this node is connected to other node by any relationship in any direction.

My query returns results, but It's not what I expected:

```
MATCH (Parent:typeA)-[R]-(Child:typeB)
WITH Parent, Child, count(R) as ChildCount
WHERE ChildCount > 3
RETURN Parent, Child, ChildCount
```

It usually returns things with `ChildCount=1` where I can manually query those things and check that they have more children of this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns the Parent nodes that have > 3 Child nodes related through R

```
MATCH (Parent:typeA)
WHERE SIZE([(Parent)-[R]-(Child:typeB) | Child]) > 3
RETURN Parent
```

or this, if you need the children

```
MATCH (Parent:typeA)-[R]-(Child:typeB)
WITH Parent, COLLECT(Child) AS children
WHERE SIZE(children) > 3
RETURN Parent,children
```